# Showing elements in JSON Array to the webpage

Tags: javascript, python, mysql, json

I am new to web development, and currently I am working on a simple dashboard that makes a query to a database and plotting graphs based on pairs of a timestamp and a value(num_requests).

As a preliminary step, I wanted to display the pairs on the webpage.

When I put all timestamps together and all num_requests together, they showed as concatenated strings, although it took minutes to show up.

However, as I made them a list of pairs and pass them to Javascript function in the form of JSON array, and iterate through that JSON array using `for` loop, it does not show up even after an hour.

Is there anything I am doing wrong? If so, how can I fix it?

FYI, The database is quite huge. It has more than a million rows.

The following snippet is the **Python** code where I make queries to a MySQL server and formatting the result into JSON.

```
c = cherrypy.thread_data.db.cursor() 
query = """select refresh_time,
                  num_requests
             from modeling_stats_hourly group by refresh_time limit 100"""
c.execute(query) 
res = c.fetchall()
c.close()

jsres = [[str(x[0]), x[1]] for x in res]
return json.dumps(jsres)
```

The **Javascript** code below is where the data is passed in JSON form and is put to the web page.

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
    if(xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
        var myData = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
        var str = "";
        for(var i = 0; i < myData.length; i++) {
            str = str + 'timestamp: ' + myData[i][0] + ' and num_requests: ' + myData[i][1] + '\n';
        }
        document.getElementById("Data").innerHTML = str;
    }
}
```

The whole blocks of codes that include the aforementioned parts are below.

```
class AjaxApp(object):
    @cherrypy.expose
    def index(self):
        # Sample page that displays the number of records in "table" 
        # Open a cursor, using the DB connection for the current thread 
        return """
        <html>
        <head>
        <script lang="javascript">
        function GetData()
        {
            // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
                xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
            else// code for IE6, IE5
                xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");

            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
            {
                if(xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
                {
                    var myData = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
                    var str = "";
                    for(var i = 0; i < myData.length; i++) {
                        str = str + 'timestamp: ' + myData[i][0] + ' and num_requests: ' + myData[i][1] + '\n';
                    }
                    document.getElementById("Data").innerHTML = str;
                }
            }

            xmlhttp.open("GET","/submit222", true);
            xmlhttp.send();
        }
        </script>
        </head>            
            <body onload="GetData();">
                <div id="Data">hi</div>
            </body>
        </html>
        """

    @cherrypy.expose
    def submit222(self):
        # Sample page that displays the number of records in "table" 
        # Open a cursor, using the DB connection for the current thread 
        c = cherrypy.thread_data.db.cursor() 
        query = """select refresh_time,
                          num_requests
                     from modeling_stats_hourly group by refresh_time limit 100"""
        c.execute(query) 
        res = c.fetchall()
        c.close()

        jsres = [[str(x[0]), x[1]] for x in res]
        return json.dumps(jsres)
```

Comment: Have you looked into something like Emberjs? http://emberjs.com

Comment: No, but should I? I think this is relatively light stuff that could be done without the help of outside package.

Comment: then try jQuery. With [.append()](https://api.jquery.com/append/) you can do what you desire

Comment: Please tell me the cause of failure in my code. Only then I will know why I should consider jQuery or Emberjs.

Comment: I found out the reason. It was because of the '\n' character attached at the end. It's so strange though. I thought regexes like '\n' were common across languages.(I'm new to Javascript)